# Dowloading Image using URL

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to download an image using a URL and a button in my app. When I'm running it on my phone, I,m not able to download the image. Can anyone please point out the problem with this. Thanks for the help in advance :)

This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView download;

public void downloadImage(View view){

    DownloadImage image = new DownloadImage();
    Bitmap result;
    try {
        result = image.execute("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bart_Simpson_200px.png").get();
        download.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    download = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}

public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap Image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
            return Image;
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I would very strongly recommend that you use Glide and not an AsyncTask. I use it for all my image loading, local or remote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can download image from url in two ways

**1**.you can user [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load image from url look the below code it can help you in simple way

**compile this library**

```
   implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
```

**than load image like this**

```
 Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
        .load(url)
        .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.booked_circle).error(R.drawable.booked_circle))
        .into(imageview);
```

**2 .try this if you dont want to use third party library**

```
 new DownloadImage(imamgeview).execute(url);
```

**create a Async Task**

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = (ImageView ) bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error", e.getStackTrace().toString());

    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
}
```

i hope that it will work in your case

Answer (score 0):

You did not call the function

```
downloadImage(view);
```

In the oncreate (after the findviewbyid line)

Also check if the internet permision is in the Android Manifest file :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Having said that you should use a library like Glide\Picasso\Ion etc... much better than asynctask for this purpuse

https://github.com/bumptech/glide - Glide

https://github.com/koush/ion - Ion

http://square.github.io/picasso/ - picasso

Hope it helped.