# How can i display images that i am receiving from (server) in a string ? Here is the code:

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

How can i display images that i am receiving from (server) in a string ? 
I'm using `AsyncTask`

Here is the code:

**AsyncTask**

```
public class sendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String> {

    String response="";
    Context context;


    sendRequest(Context context)
    {
        this.context=context;
       // this.list=list;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {



    URL url;
    BufferedReader reader = null;


    String link =<i> "example.com/example.php";</i>


    try {
        url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(5 * 1000);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.connect();

        String inputToFile = URLEncoder.encode("mName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8");



        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(inputToFile);
        writer.flush();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

//Here i have add data to string how to display images 

//The result of Toast in onpostexecute is

//{"images":[{"image":"http:\/\/example.com\/example.jpg"},{"image":"http:\/\/example.com\/example.jpg"}]}

            response += line;


        }

        //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        //Toast.makeText(context,bmp.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        //   DonorList.setText("Url Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
        response = "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //   DonorList.setText("Connection could not be opened");
        e.printStackTrace();
        response += "Exception: " + e.getMessage();
    }

        return response;

    }// DO IN BACKGROUND



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

        super.onPostExecute(response);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Recieved: "+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Images are binary - how do you expect to display as text?

Comment: Please tell us you problem in brief. only code will not help? what is that you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to display images in image view that i am receiving from server.

Comment: Your code shows you have a json data in response and you want to take out the bitmap from url? is that so? if yes the where is the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724824/dowloading-image-using-url/44724972#44724972

Comment: If you dig google properly _Download image from server_ definitely you will get solutions.

Comment: Ashwani yes but dont know how?

Answer (score 0):

Use Glide library for loading image in ImageView

```
Glide.with(context).load(image_url).into(imageView);
```