# how to set imageview from Mysql in adapter using string value

Tags: android, mysql, string, android-recyclerview

I want to set image in recyclerview, and the image from mysql database. I have tried using `imageView.setImageResource(motorType.getImage)` but can't because *setImageResource* using int, while i save my image in database using string like */files/image-f875803a-164f-11e8-b31a-005056b25997.png*

so how can I set my Image in adapter? thankyou..

**this is my model code (ImageMotor.java)**

```
public class ImageMotor {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private String image;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
}
```

**CatalogActivity.java**

```
private void refreshingData() {
    API.getImageMotor().enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<ImageMotor>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<ImageMotor>> call, Response<ArrayList<ImageMotor>> response) {
            datas = response.body();
            tempDatas = datas;
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new TypeMotorAdapter(datas));
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<ImageMotor>> call, Throwable throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(CatalogActivity.this,"Data Kosong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
}

public class TypeMotorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TypeMotorAdapter.TypeMotorViewHolder> {

    List<ImageMotor> dataSet;

    public TypeMotorAdapter(List<ImageMotor> data) {
        this.dataSet = data;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeMotorViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_catalog_item, parent, false);

        return new TypeMotorViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TypeMotorViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ImageMotor motorType = dataSet.get(position);

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(motorType.getImage());
        holder.tv_motor.setText(motorType.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(dataSet == null){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return dataSet.size();
        }
    }

    public class TypeMotorViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;

        public TextView tv_motor;

        public TypeMotorViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_type_motor);
            tv_motor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_motor);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776851/load-image-from-url

Comment: is it file path or url that run on browser ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dowloading Image using URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724824/dowloading-image-using-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Glide](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/) for this purpose :

```
Glide.with(this).load(motorType.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
```

In gradle :

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
```

For Picasso use :

```
Picasso.with(this).load(motorType.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: @Ratri If you are not getting full url you can append it like `String url = baseURL+motorType.getImage()`

Comment: Try the answer and let me know if any problem

Comment: @VishvaDave **FYI** latest version of glide is `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'`

Comment: @Ratri Happy to help :) Happy coding :)

Comment: @VishvaDave **`latest version has bugs`** which bugs

Comment: @VishvaDave read this https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues there is no issue of `performence issues. Slow loading`

Comment: @VishvaDave its from all version not from `com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1` please read carefully from my given link

Comment: @VishvaDave happy to help you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show image in ImageView and store also in mysql in string format follow this steps. I use glide library for load image data and recyclerview for display feed.

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1' library or picasso.
```

**Activity**

```
public static String imagePath;
//Request Camera Permission for User
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Myutility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from Library"))
                galleryIntent();
    }
}

//Intent For Gallary
private void galleryIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);//
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), RESULT_LOAD_IMG);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (data != null) {
        String picturePath = "";
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        if (selectedImage == null) {
            selectedImage = Uri.EMPTY;
        }
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(picturePath)
                    .error(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.error))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.error)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(imageView);
            cursor.close();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap;
        int width = imageView.getWidth();
        int height = imageView.getHeight();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        imagePath = picturePath;

    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && null != data) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.cancelevent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}


public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageViewAddImage:

           onPickPhoto();

            break;


        //image select click
        case R.id.imageView:
            final CharSequence[] items = {getString(R.string.chooseForLibrary),
                    getString(R.string.cancel)};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddReferenceActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.titleAddPhoto);
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    boolean result = Myutility.checkPermission(AddReferenceActivity.this);
                    if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                        userChoosenTask = "Choose from Library";
                        if (result)
                            galleryIntent();

                    } else if (items[item].equals(getString(R.string.userclickCancel))) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();

        default:
            break;
```

**ADAPTER CLASS**

```
public class AddReferenceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<PersonFeed> personArray = new ArrayList<>();

public AddReferenceAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PersonFeed> arrayFeeds) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.personArray = arrayFeeds;
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.carditemview, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view); // Change The Return Value
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holderMain, final int position) {

    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) holderMain;

    PersonFeed feedInfoObject = personArray.get(position);

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(feedInfoObject.getUrl())
            .error(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.maan))
            .bitmapTransform(new RoundedCornersTransformation(mContext, 50, 0))
            .fitCenter()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.maan)
            .crossFade(30)
            .into(holder.ImageView);

    holder.textviewPersonName.setText(feedInfoObject.getPersonName());
    holder.textviewpersionDesignation.setText(feedInfoObject.getPersondesignation());
    holder.textviewPersonDetail.setText(feedInfoObject.getPersonDetail());


    holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //creating a popup menu
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, holder.buttonViewOption);
            //inflating menu from xml resource
            popup.inflate(R.menu.options_menu);
            //adding click listener

            //delete items on recyclerview event
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.menu1:
                            removeitem(position);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();

                            break;

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            //displaying the popup
            popup.show();
        }
    });
}

//remove items and set tip message for user
private void removeitem(int position) {
    personArray.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, personArray.size());
    if (personArray.isEmpty()) {
        ((MainActivity) mContext).Nodaatafound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((MainActivity) mContext).recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return personArray.size();
}

private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    //declar controls
    private final View myView;
    private final ImageView ImageView;
    private final TextView textviewPersonName;
    private TextView textviewpersionDesignation;
    private TextView textviewPersonDetail;
    private TextView buttonViewOption;


    private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myView = itemView;


        textviewPersonName = myView.findViewById(R.id.textviewPersonName);

        textviewpersionDesignation = myView.findViewById(R.id.textviewpersionDesignation);
        textviewPersonDetail = myView.findViewById(R.id.textviewPersonDetail);
        ImageView = myView.findViewById(R.id.cardimage);


        buttonViewOption = myView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOptions);

        //note : if your layout is linear then set Linearlayout objects.
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ImageView.getLayoutParams();

        //layoutParams.height = dataToSet;
        ImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }


}
```

}

Don't forget to set camera,internet or storage permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```